# Android actionbar won't show title or settings

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

Little confused on how to show an actionbar on my second activity. Hopefully I didn't provide too much. Basically to clarify, the actionbar works perfect on my MainActivity (title shows and settings button), but I can only see the action bar on my other activities (NO title or buttons) I also took a look in menu_main.xml and noticed the context was set to my MainActivity, so I made menu_attractions.xml and changed the context to the proper activity, but that still didn't show the title or settings button. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Nothing fancy for my MainActivity (this is where I assume the magic happens for the title/buttons??)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
  <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
  <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>



  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />



 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And for the MainActivity class, I search for the toolbar below... and inflate the menu

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    attractionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activityButton);
}


 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
       present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
   }
```

Here's my actionbar

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

### Now... here's my second activity

```
public class AttractionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button scheduleButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.d_activities);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    scheduleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activies_Schedule);
    scheduleButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent scheduleIntent = new Intent(AttractionsActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class);
            startActivity(scheduleIntent);
        }


    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_attractions, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

### here's my layout for my second activity activity

```
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/img_252413"
tools:context="AttractionsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/d_activities">


<include layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:id="@+id/include" />


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"


        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Schedule"
        android:id="@+id/activies_Schedule" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Maps"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Performers"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sponsors"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Statics"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exibitors"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Food"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>






 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems You Have Changed the Theme for Your Second Activity.Try the following

**Step 1:** Add this in Your **Styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.AttractionsActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**Step 2:** Add this in Manifest.Xml

```
<activity
android:name=".AttractionsActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AttractionsActivity"
/>
```